# C# CSOM Console App To Return Data From SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I am attempting to query a SharePoint site and write data to the console.  I am getting an error of

> the version of the request is 15.0.0.0 and it is not supported by the server.  The server supports the following versions 14.0.0.0

On this line in my code:

```
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

But I installed both the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime` from NuGet and if I click on the reference and look at the version the version for both shows 14.0.0.0

What must I do to overcome this error and allow my code to execute properly?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using ? SP Online or On premise 2013 or 2016 ?

Comment: Sharepoint Online

Comment: did you use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7l5D.png) nuget package ? If not, create a new project and add this nuget and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is completly related to dlls only.
Try to copy the dlls from SharePoint 2010 server and check it

Comment: I used Nuget to get the .dll where can I get the dll from SharePoint 2010?  It is not installed on the PC I am working on (why I am using CSOM)

Comment: do you have access to the server

Comment: I do not have access to the server